# Apache Mahout for Android

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, mahout, recommendation-engine

I am making a music recommendation Android app. I am trying to add Apache Mahout to the dependency, yet the library methods and classes are unavailable. Kindly point out what is going wrong .

Here's the build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ashutosh.music_player"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'org.apache.mahout:mahout:0.10.0'
}
```

If you know anything as an alternative to mahout for recommendation system, kindly suggest that.

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting at compile?

Comment: Why do you want to use Apache Mahout for your Android App. It's a machine learning library on top of Hadoop and uses Map Reduce for it's most of algorithms. You can use other library like Weka or Tensorflow